# QVideoWidget doesn't resize well

Tags: c++, qt, multimedia, qtmultimedia, qvideowidget

I have a Qt application which simply captures from the default webcam and shows it on a QVideoWidget. In the ui, I have a simple MainWindow with a QGraphicsView inside a VerticalLayout:

ui design

[image]

My mainwindow.cpp=============================================

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_viewfinder = new QVideoWidget(ui->captureView);
    m_camera = new QCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
    m_camera->setViewfinder(m_viewfinder);

    m_camera->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    m_camera->stop();
    delete m_viewfinder;
    delete m_camera;
    delete ui;
}
```

When I execute this, I get the application running, but the video contents do not scale according to the mainwindow size. Examples:

When I start the application

[image]

Resizing mainwindow down

[image]

Resizing mainwindow up

[image]

Is there some way to make the video content resize well and fit the available area?
I have seen this answer: [QVideoWidget: Video is cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374158/qvideowidget-video-is-cut-off), but it doesn't offer any solution that works for me. When use the QGraphicsView-QGraphicsScene-QGraphicsVideoItem chain, I see nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the following instruction:

```
m_viewfinder = new QVideoWidget(ui->captureView);
```

You are setting as the parent of `m_viewfinder` to `captureView`, so the positions of `m_viewfinder` will be relative to `captureView`, but this does not indicate that it will be the same size as the parent.

One of the easiest ways to do this is to use a layout. Also, it is not necessary to create the `QGraphicsWidget` or the `QVBoxLayout`, so I recommend you to delete it and get the design as it was established by default:

[image]

and then we establish a layout that is placed in the `centralWidget`, and in this layout we add the `QVideoWidget`.

```
...
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_viewfinder = new QVideoWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget);
    lay->addWidget(m_viewfinder);
    m_camera = new QCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
    m_camera->setViewfinder(m_viewfinder);

    m_camera->start();
}
...
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49410557) you can find the complete example.

Comment: The answer is simple, the video can't be 100 % width and height of the underlaying QWidget all the time. The video keeps a specific ratio and horizontal or vertical spaces will appear.

Comment: @user3606329 
The widget has the correct width and height, the video does not. That can not be changed since that depends on the file or in your case the resolution of your camera.

Comment: @user3606329 
explain why you tell me crazy downvoter ?.

Comment: @ eyllanesc : you're not, I called it back and upvoted your answer now. greetings.

Comment: @ eyllanesc the comment has been already removed and I'm always nice.